# How to connect string REST with JPA?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

I'm following the guide at http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/ , which is like the hello world for this... GET requests works perfectly, but when trying the POST they suggest (I'm using Rest Client Chrome extension), with json

```
{ "firstName" : "Frodo", "lastName" : "Baggins" }
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    cause: {
        cause: null
        message: "Unrecognized token 'firstName': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@29508db1; line: 1, column: 11]"
    }
    message: "Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'firstName': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@29508db1; line: 1, column: 11]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'firstName': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@29508db1; line: 1, column: 11]"
}
```

How can I fix this? Why is it happening?

Comment: Works for me. The app is so simple that you can post the three classes you have.

Comment: If you [clone the guide project](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/#_how_to_complete_this_guide) and `cd` into `./completed` and [run](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/#_run_the_service) the project, does it still happen using the same request? I also tried and worked fine...

Comment: Also getting the same error message on a put request with a seemingly valid String content.

Comment: I had to enclose the string content into a JSON.stringify() call. It now works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some issues whit POST method and Spring, when Cross-Site Request Forgery (csrf) protection is enabled (in spring security - `<csrf/>`).  The issue (that I had) was that the error doesn't seem to indicate this was the problem but adding the following to my forms did the trick:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to verify if you had Content-Type:application/json when you send the request

Comment: yes, I had that content type when doing the request :( thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() the content or just put single quotes, that fixes the problem.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/people',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '{"firstName":"xx","lastName":"xx"}',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Comment: I wasn't doing it from jQuery, and seems it was a Spring configuration

Comment: This can't be done without stringifying. Double vs .single quotes doesn't matter.